# CRM 2011 Outlook Client JScript Errors

Tags: javascript, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Out of the blue one of our users started experiencing JScript errors when using the Outlook client for MS Dynamics CRM 2011. We are on Rollup 14, for both the client and the server itself, but upgrading them both to 18 did not resolve the issue. I've tried emptying temporary files, deleting caches, and adding our server to the IE trusted sites list, but nothing has fixed it. I've tried clean installations of Outlook and the client itself.

The problem occurs when trying to 'Set Regarding' from the Outlook client. The error messages begin immediately and say 'Script Error', usually something about XPathEvaluator.

If I click through the prompts, the search box is non-functioning and the 'Search' preview text does not go away. I don't know anything about how to trace with 'debugger'. Has anyone else encountered this or a similar error?

Comment: If you have roaming windows profiles, try asking that one user to login to a different machine and recreatw the issue. At least you can isolate if it is an environment issue.

Comment: post the error content and/or a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell for the Outlook client is IE, and IE 11 apparently is the cause of these errors. I don't have high enough reputation to post images but I'll add them when I do. The solution we used was to roll IE back to IE 10.